# MVC and Moles test project

Tags: model-view-controller, version, moles

I am having a sample mvc project and Moles test project. When i am trying to build my test project i am getting the following error.

Friend access was granted to 'Sample.Web.UI.Tests, PublicKey=(Key)', but the output assembly is named 'Sample.Web.UI.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Try adding a reference to 'WBS.Workware.Web.UI.Tests, PublicKey=(Key)' or changing the output assembly name to match.   e:\Projects\Sample.Web.UI\bin\Sample.Web.UI.dll Sample.Web.UI.Tests

How can solve this error?

Comment: Is this the problem with signing assemblies ?

Answer (score 0):

Friend access is a new common language runtime (CLR) feature that enables an assembly to see another assembly's non-public types. This error occurs when the assembly granting friend access specifies the wrong name for the grantee assembly.

I'm guessing you need to change the name passed into InternalsVisibleTo. For example:
    InternalsVisibleTo("WBS.Workware.Web.UI.Tests")